# If p(B|A)=1, does that imply that p(~A ∪ B)=1?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Either A or ~A must happen. And if A happens, then since p(B|A)=1, we know that B happens, which means that ~A∪B happens. And if A doesn't happen, then ~A∪B happens. This leads me to believe that p(~A ∪ B) = 1. Is this conclusion correct, or am I severely misunderstanding something?

Comment: $P(A^\complement \cup B)=P(B\cap A)+P( A^\complement)=P(B\mid A)P(A)+1-P(A)=1$.

Comment: It is correct, though your use of "happens" is not quite precise

Comment: @Henry I think "happens" should be taken to mean "in a measurable subset". Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu(\Omega) = 1$. Then, given $A, B \in \Sigma, \mu(A \cap B) / \mu(A) = 1$, does that mean $\mu(A^c \cup B) = 1$?

Answer (score 1):

The condition $P(B \mid A) = 1$ means that $P(B \cap A) = P(A).$ But we also know that
$$
P(A) = P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap B^\complement) = P(A) + P(A \cap B^\complement),
$$
which implies that $P(A \cap B^\complement) = 0.$ Therefore,
$$
P(B) = P(B \cap A) + P(B \cap A^\complement) = P(A) + P(B \cap A^\complement),
$$
which yields
$$
\begin{align*}
P(A^\complement \cup B) &= P(A^\complement) + P(B) - P(A^\complement \cap B) \\
&= P(A^\complement) + P(B) - P(B) + P(A) \\
&= P(A^\complement) + P(A) = 1.
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

Visualize the situation via a Venn diagram, using circles to represent the events A and B.

The constraint $~p(B|A) = 1,~$ which signifies that if event A occurs, then event B must also occur, analogizes (visually) to A being a subset of B.

This implies that when you consider the complementary set $~A^c,~$ the only *region missing* from this complementary set is A, which is totally contained in the set B.

Therefore, you must have that $~~~$ Universe $~= ~A^c \cup A \subseteq A^c \cup B.$